# `ode45` and tspan error Attempted to access

Tags: matlab, ode

I'm using `ode45` to solve second order differential equation. the time span is determined based on how many numbers in `txt` file, therefore, the time span is defined as follows

```
i    = 1;
t(i) = 0;
dt   = 0.1;
numel(theta_d)
while ( i < numel(theta_d) )
   i = i + 1;
   t(i) = t(i-1) + dt;
end
```

Now the time elements should not exceed the size of `txt` (i.e. `numel(theta_d)`). In `main.m`, I have

```
x0 = [0; 0];
options= odeset('Reltol',dt,'Stats','on');
[t, x] = ode45('ODESolver', t, x0, options);
```

and `ODESolver.m` header is

```
function dx = ODESolver(t, x)
```

If I run the code, I'm getting this error

```
Attempted to access theta_d(56); index out of bounds because numel(theta_d)=55.

Error in ODESolver (line 29)
theta_dDot  = ( theta_d(i) - theta_dPrev ) / dt;
```

Why the `ode45` is not being fixed with the time span?

---

Edit: this is the entire code

`main.m`

```
clear all
clc

global error theta_d dt;
error = 0;


theta_d = load('trajectory.txt');




i    = 1;
t(i) = 0;
dt   = 0.1;
numel(theta_d)
while ( i < numel(theta_d) )
  i = i + 1;
  t(i) = t(i-1) + dt;
end

x0 = [pi/4; 0];
options= odeset('Reltol',dt,'Stats','on');
[t, x] = ode45(@ODESolver, t, x0, options);

 %e = x(:,1) - theta_d; % Error theta


plot(t, x(:,2), 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
title('Tracking Problem','Interpreter','LaTex');
xlabel('time (sec)');
ylabel('$\dot{\theta}(t)$', 'Interpreter','LaTex');
grid on
```

and `ODESolver.m`

```
function dx = ODESolver(t, x)

persistent i theta_dPrev

if isempty(i)
    i = 1;
    theta_dPrev = 0;
end

global error theta_d dt ; 

dx = zeros(2,1);

%Parameters:
m = 0.5;       % mass (Kg)
d = 0.0023e-6; % viscous friction coefficient
L = 1;         % arm length (m)
I = 1/3*m*L^2; % inertia seen at the rotation axis. (Kg.m^2)
g = 9.81;      % acceleration due to gravity m/s^2


% PID tuning
Kp = 5;
Kd = 1.9;
Ki = 0.02;

% theta_d first derivative
theta_dDot  = ( theta_d(i) - theta_dPrev ) / dt;
theta_dPrev = theta_d(i);


% u: joint torque
u = Kp*(theta_d(i) - x(1)) + Kd*( theta_dDot - x(2)) + Ki*error;
error = error + (theta_dDot - x(1));

dx(1) = x(2);
dx(2) = 1/I*(u - d*x(2) - m*g*L*sin(x(1)));

i = i + 1;
end
```

and this is the error

```
Attempted to access theta_d(56); index out of bounds because numel(theta_d)=55.

Error in ODESolver (line 28)
theta_dDot  = ( theta_d(i) - theta_dPrev ) / dt;

Error in ode45 (line 261)
    f(:,2) = feval(odeFcn,t+hA(1),y+f*hB(:,1),odeArgs{:});

Error in main (line 21)
[t, x] = ode45(@ODESolver, t, x0, options);
```

Comment: What is `theta_d`? A vector of values? Try `t=0:st:numel(theta_d)` instead of your `while` loop.

Comment: @David, yes it is a vector of values. `t=0:st:numel(theta_d)` is not correct. It will create more samples than the size of `txt`. You can generate `theta_d` to be  `theta_d = rand(5,1)`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, try this instead: `0:dt:(dt*(numel(theta_d)-1))`

Comment: Does that solve your problem? Or is the integration still causing trouble?

Comment: You provide an error message, but none of the code you provided has the line that produces the error (which the error message has helpfully provided). Also, unless you're using a ten year old version of Matlab, you should use an anonymous function to specify your integration function: ` ode45(@ODESolver, t, x0, options);`.

Comment: @David, sorry I forgot to delete something in my code to get it to work. I'm still having same problem.

Comment: I was having `if ( i == 56 ) i = 55; end` to run the code. Now the code is running only if I force `i` to not exceed the 56.

Comment: @horchler, I've added the entire code. Hope this helps

Comment: For ppl who suggested to close this topic. Please reconsider the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is because you have data at discrete time points, but `ode45` needs to be able to calculate the derivative at any time point in your time range. Once it solves the problem, it will interpolate the results back onto your desired time points. So it will calculate the derivative many times more than at just the time points you specified, thus your `i` counter will not work at all.

Since you have discrete data, the only way to proceed with `ode45` is to interpolate `theta_d` to any time `t`. You have a list of values `theta_d` corresponding to times `0:dt:(dt*(numel(theta_d)-1))`, so to interpolate to a particular time `t`, use `interp1(0:dt:(dt*(numel(theta_d)-1)),theta_d,t)`, and I turned this into an anonymous function to give the interpolated value of `theta_p` at a given time `t`

Then your derivative function will look like

```
function dx = ODESolver(t, x,thetaI)

dx = zeros(2,1);

%Parameters:
m = 0.5;       % mass (Kg)
d = 0.0023e-6; % viscous friction coefficient
L = 1;         % arm length (m)
I = 1/3*m*L^2; % inertia seen at the rotation axis. (Kg.m^2)
g = 9.81;      % acceleration due to gravity m/s^2

% PID tuning
Kp = 5;
Kd = 1.9;
Ki = 0.02;

% theta_d first derivative
dt=1e-4;
theta_dDot  = (thetaI(t) - theta(I-dt)) / dt;
%// Note thetaI(t) is the interpolated theta_d values at time t

% u: joint torque
u = Kp*(thetaI(t) - x(1)) + Kd*( theta_dDot - x(2)) + Ki*error;
error = error + (theta_dDot - x(1));

dx=[x(2);  1/I*(u - d*x(2) - m*g*L*sin(x(1)))];    
end
```

and you will have to define `thetaI=@(t) interp1(0:dt:(dt*(numel(theta_d)-1)),theta_d,t);` before calling `ode45` using `[t, x] = ode45(@(t,x) ODESolver(t,x,thetaI, t, x0, options);`.

I removed a few things from `ODESolver` and changed how the derivative was computed.

Note I can't test this, but it should get you on the way.